# find a particular line in a log file based on a substring - Python

Tags: python, regex, hadoop

I have the following piece of a `Hadoop` cluster:

```
==> namenode_32: 14/11/02 02:19:32 INFO namenode.NNStorage: Storage directory /data/1/dfs/nn has been successfully formatted.
==> namenode_32: 14/11/02 02:19:32 INFO namenode.NNStorage: Storage directory /nfsmount/dfs/nn has been successfully formatted.
==> namenode_32: 14/11/02 02:19:32 INFO namenode.FSImage: Saving image file /nfsmount/dfs/nn/current/fsimage.ckpt_0000000000000000000 using no compression
==> namenode_32: 14/11/02 02:19:32 INFO namenode.FSImage: Saving image file /data/1/dfs/nn/current/fsimage.ckpt_0000000000000000000 using no compression
==> namenode_32: 14/11/02 02:19:32 INFO namenode.FSImage: Image file of size 115 saved in 0 seconds.
==> namenode_32: 14/11/02 02:19:32 INFO namenode.FSImage: Image file of size 115 saved in 0 seconds.
==> namenode_32: 14/11/02 02:19:32 INFO namenode.NNStorageRetentionManager: Going to retain 1 images with txid >= 0
==> namenode_32: 14/11/02 02:19:32 INFO util.ExitUtil: Exiting with status 0
==> namenode_32: 14/11/02 02:19:32 INFO namenode.NameNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG: 
==> namenode_32: /************************************************************
==> namenode_32: SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NameNode at ip-10-45-129-157.ec2.internal/10.45.129.157
==> namenode_32: ************************************************************/
==> namenode_32:  * Starting Hadoop namenode: 
==> namenode_32: starting namenode, logging to /var/log/hadoop-hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-namenode-ip-10-45-129-157.out
==> namenode_32:  * Starting Hadoop secondarynamenode: 
==> namenode_32: starting secondarynamenode, logging to /var/log/hadoop-hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-secondarynamenode-ip-10-45-129-157.out
==> namenode_32:  * Starting Hadoop jobtracker: 
==> namenode_32: starting jobtracker, logging to /var/log/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/hadoop-hadoop-jobtracker-ip-10-45-129-157.out
```

and I'm trying to find the `ip address` of such cluster. I know the `SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NameNode ...` it's what I'm looking for is the tuple of the private `DNS` and `private ip`. For that articular example, I got:

```
(ip-10-45-129-157.ec2.internal, 10.45.129.157)
```

so I tried:

```
import re
expr = "SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NameNode at"
s = re.search(expr, log)
>>> print (s.group())
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NameNode at
```

which is not what I want ... How can I produce such tuple using regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use multiple capturing groups to capture the context afterwords.

```
>>> re.search(r'SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NameNode at (.+)/(.+)', log).groups()
('ip-10-45-129-157.ec2.internal', '10.45.129.157')
```

You could write your expression as:

```
>>> re.search(r'SHUTDOWN_MSG:.+at (.+)/(.+)', log).groups()
```

Answer (score 2):

Use multiple capturing groups after that search string:

```
>>> expr = 'SHUTDOWN_MSG:.+at (.+)/(.+)'
>>> re.search(expr, log).groups()
('ip-10-45-129-157.ec2.internal', '10.45.129.157')
```

Answer (score 0):

capture groups using `()`

```
import re
f=open('log_file','r').read()
re.findall("SHUTDOWN_MSG:.+at (.+)/(.+)",f)
```

re.findall() will not stop on first find it will find till it reach end of file, so it will give you all match